# SSH Tunnels and ROS

Tags: ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there a way to tunnel ROS traffic over SSH, for example in cases where the ROS MASTER is not on the same network as another machine that I want to be able to connect to it. Thanks!

Edit: Never mind, I figured out how to use openvpn to achieve the same result from http://lists.willowgarage.com/pipermail/pr2-admins/2010-June/000055.html . But maybe this is useful for other people.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11163/ssh-tunnels-and-ros/) by [Ibrahim](https://answers.ros.org/users/331/ibrahim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 307 on 2011-09-09

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you mentioned OpenVPN is the most common solution to this, and is what we use at Willow and on the PR2s.

---

Originally posted by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) with karma: 1145 on 2011-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-09-10**:
ROS uses ports allocated to it by the system, so they're not known ahead of time which makes setting up the forwarding hard, unless you basically forward all ports.

**Comment by [Ibrahim](https://answers.ros.org/users/331/ibrahim/) on 2011-09-09**:
That's what I had thought, but after figuring it out I'm still a little curious as to whether it's possible to do it via ssh tunnels or not. But I guess because ROS nodes use a lot of different ports it'd be hard to do.